# upgrade to 12.04 causes inactive desktop

Tags: upgrade

I recently upgraded my ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04. The upgrade happened successfully. Now, on login screen, i cant do any thing except entering password. Mouse pointer doesnt move and i cant select any option for login.

Anyhow, once i am login, desktop seems freezing and no any icon is active. No mouse movement. The only thing which i can do is Ctrl-Alt_del. And again the same problem.

Could some please help me out

Answer (score 0):

The option you want from the login screen is obtained by clicking the 'Ubuntu' icon to the right of the login dialogue box.  I'm not sure, but I think you ought to be able to tab to this and select.  The option you want is Unity 2D.